# clear input with particular type attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

this:

```
$("#registrant input").val('');
```

will clear all the `<input>` inside the div `#registarnt`.

But, how can i exclude the input with particular type? (like "submit")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#registrant input[type!="submit"]').val('')`

or better still

`$('#registrant input[type="text"]').val('')`

Comment: OR `$('#registrant :text').val('')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "[attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)" selector to match on the `type` attribute. For example:

```
$("#registrant input[type='text']").val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution that will restore the original value if the field is still empty on blur. This can be used site-wide.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clearInput = '';
    // on focus: store the original value, then clear it
    $('input[type="text"]').focus( function() {
        clearInput = $(this).val();
        $(this).val('');
    });
    // on blur: if the value is still empty, display the original value
    $('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
        if($(this).val()=='') {
            $(this).val(clearInput);
        }
    });
});
```

If you would like to exclude only one input type you could change the following lines:

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus( function() { 
$('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
```

to something like this:

```
$('input').not('input[type="submit"]').focus( function() { 
$('input').not('input[type="submit"]').blur(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these selectors to filter input types:

- [:button](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/)
- [:checkbox](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)
- [:radio](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/)
- [:submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/)
- [:text](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/)

So in your case (also using [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) as you want to skip submit):

```
$("#registrant input:not(:submit)").val('');
```

or

```
$("#registrant input").not(":submit").val('');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K6WUu/